# EAN Expedia Hotel Information URL Service not found

Tags: php, xml, api

I've been searching for an answer here and in Google but can't seem to have a definite answer, this is my first post in StackOverflow but have been a regular visitor for some years and I have learned a lot from this site, so thanks!

My problem is with Expedia's API regarding Hotel information: http://developer.ean.com/docs/read/hotel_info/examples/XML_Default_Content

My problematic URL is:
http://api.ean.com/ean‑services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=1&apiKey=9kxdnz8ngbf7gmwkzm4qkgjw&customerSessionId=0ABAA850-419E-A913-D072-4A24A390607C&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0&customerIpAddress=2.50.181.154&locale=en_UScurrencyCode=USD&xml=1175480

I'm getting a "596 Service Not Found" error.

I apologize if this has been asked before, and many thanks for the help!!!

Comment: This sounds like a question for Expedia's developer support.

Comment: I've got it working thanks! the problem is when I copy / pasted the url the part /ean-services/ needs to be typed written manually, I think it's because of the "-".  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The example in EAN's Developer Hub for making a [Hotel Info request](http://developer.ean.com/docs/hotel_info/examples/XML_Default_Content) has been fixed.

The problem:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean&#8209;services/rs/hotel/v3/info?
```

The solution:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean&#45;services/rs/hotel/v3/info?
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be affiliated with EAN in any way, would you? If so, you should make sure to disclose that when talking favorably about them.

Comment: I am affiliated with EAN, and you have a valid point that I was having a little too much fun with my answer. I edited it to stick to just the facts.

Answer (score 0):

You also didn't enter the xml parameter correctly. It should have been like this:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=1&apiKey=9kxdnz8ngbf7gmwkzm4qkgjw&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac 0OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0&customerIpAddress=2.50.181.154&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&xml=<HotelInformationRequest>
  <hotelId>122212</hotelId>
  <options>0</options>
</HotelInformationRequest>
```

You could just forget about using xml and use the REST format:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=1&apiKey=9kxdnz8ngbf7gmwkzm4qkgjw&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac 0OS X 10.8; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0&customerIpAddress=2.50.181.154&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&hotelId=122212&options=0
```

By the way, I just found a SDK for Android from Expedia Affiliate Network. https://github.com/ExpediaInc/ean-android

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this its working good.

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/info?cid=55505&minorRev=1&apiKey=9kxdnz8ngbf7gmwkzm4qkgjw&customerSessionId=&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0%20%28Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.8;%20rv:19.0%29%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/19.0&customerIpAddress=&locale=en_UScurrencyCode=USD
```

You can add this xml to your code

**`&xml=<HotelInfo><hotelId>407696</hotelId><city></city><options>DEFAULT</options></HotelInfo>`**

Comment: You can just add this two line url into one line. its working