# I am getting an error when I am trying to manipulate form data in a spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Ok, I am doing something wrong here but I don't know what.
So here is the code :

hello.jspx :

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <html>
    <head><title>Simple jspx page</title></head>
    <body>
    Place content here ${message}

    <form method="get" action="sendParameters">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>City:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cityName" id="cityId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>State:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="stateName" id="stateId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Arrival Date:(MM/DD/YYYY)</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="arrivalDateName" id="arrivalDateId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Departure Date:(MM/DD/YYYY)</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="departureDateName" id="departureDateId"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

results.jspx :

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <jsp:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <html>
    <head><title>Simple jspx page</title></head>
    <body>Place content here : ${message}</body>
    </html>
</jsp:root>
```

HomeController.java :

```
package com.apress.prospring3.ch17.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello user!");
        return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/sendParameters", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createUrl(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("cityName")String cityName, @RequestParam("stateName")String stateName, @RequestParam("arrivalDateName")String arrivalDateName, @RequestParam("departureDateName")String departureDateName) throws Exception
    {
        String myUrl = "http://api.ean.com/ean‑services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=20" +
                "&cid=55505" +
                "&apiKey=123456789" +
                "&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64;) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/20.0" +
                "&customerIpAddress=192.168.1.1" +
                "&locale=en_US" +
                "&currencyCode=USD" +
                "&city=" + cityName +
                "&stateProvinceCode=" + stateName +
                "&countryCode=US" +
                "&supplierCacheTolerance=MED" +
                "&arrivalDate=" + arrivalDateName +
                "&departureDate=" + departureDateName +
                "&room1=2" +
                "&numberOfResults=1" +
                "&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED";

        URL yahoo = new URL(myUrl);
        URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();

        model.addAttribute("message", "Results ready!");
        return "results";
    }
}
```

The error appears just after I press submit, and it is the following :

> HTTP Status 500 - Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL:
>   http://api.ean.com/ean‑services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=20&cid=55505&apiKey=123456789&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64;) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/20.0&customerIpAddress=192.168.1.1&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&city=Seattle&stateProvinceCode=WA&countryCode=US&supplierCacheTolerance=MED&arrivalDate=09/04/2013&departureDate=09/05/2013&room1=2&numberOfResults=1&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: What I think is happening is that url connection fails with 400 and when you try to read the stream it throws the exception which Spring catches and shows as 500 error to you. Can you put some breakpoints or some inner `try/catch` blocks in your controller method to see where it comes from?

Comment: The line that throws the connection is the BufferedReader line.Maybe it has to do with the response from the ean api which is in xml format.

Comment: Another thing I noticed by writing the myUrl String at the console just after it is created is that ean-services becomes ean?services.What is going on here?

Comment: If i copy (in debugging mode) the url value and then paste it in a browser it does not work.If I manually erase and write by hand the dash in the ean-services part of the url, the url works.I even found a relevant problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041320/ean-expedia-hotel-information-url-service-not-found).

Comment: like the referenced question says.. there's something funky about how http://api.ean.com/ean‑services handles the -. This is not a problem with your code.